# Get Youtube video title using classname and text attribute using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, youtube, webdriver

Hi I'm using Python Selenium Webdriver to get Youtube title but keep getting more info than I'd like.
The line is:
`driver.find_element_by_class_name("style-scope ytd-video-primary-info-renderer").text`

Is there any way to fix it and make it more efficient so that it displays only the title.
Here is the test script Im using:

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from time import sleep as zz

driver = wd.Firefox(executable_path=r'./geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wma0szfIafk')
zz(4)
test_atr = driver.find_element_by_class_name("style-scope ytd-video-primary-info-renderer").text
print(test_atr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the title text *`OBI-WAN KENOBI Official Trailer (2022) Teaser`* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1.title.style-scope.ytd-video-primary-info-renderer > yt-formatted-string.style-scope.ytd-video-primary-info-renderer").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h1[@class='title style-scope ytd-video-primary-info-renderer']/yt-formatted-string[@class='style-scope ytd-video-primary-info-renderer']").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1.title.style-scope.ytd-video-primary-info-renderer > yt-formatted-string.style-scope.ytd-video-primary-info-renderer"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h1[@class='title style-scope ytd-video-primary-info-renderer']/yt-formatted-string[@class='style-scope ytd-video-primary-info-renderer']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  OBI-WAN KENOBI Official Trailer (2022) Teaser
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Comment: Thanks man it actually worked